org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException while starting Appium test
I try to run my very first test in Appium but then I get an error. My test is simple as it can be:
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumBy;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class testowyTest {

    public AndroidDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException{
        String appiumServerUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4723";

        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        dc.setCapability("appium:automationName", "uiautomator2");
        dc.setCapability("appium:app", System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/resources/apps/ApiDemos.apk");

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(appiumServerUrl),dc);
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        driver.findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("Accessibility")).click();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void close(){
        driver.quit();
    }
}```
When I run this test I get en error.


[main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [TestNG] Running:
/Users/kamilwysocki/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.2/temp-testng-customsuite.xml
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The application at '/Users/kamilwysocki/IdeaProjects/appiumDependency/resources/apps/ApiDemos.apk' does not exist or is not accessible
Host info: host: 'Kamil', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:146b:13b6:d428:6e55%en0'
Build info: version: '4.24.0', revision: '748ffc9bc3'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '14.6.1', java.version: '21.0.4'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {appium:app: /Users/kamilwysocki/IdeaPro..., appium:automationName: uiautomator2, platformName: ANDROID}]}]
Capabilities {appium:app: /Users/kamilwysocki/IdeaPro..., appium:automationName: uiautomator2, platformName: ANDROID}
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:114)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:75)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:61)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:176)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:237)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:270)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:91)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:103)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:109)
at testowyTest.setup(testowyTest.java:23)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:141)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:71)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:400)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:333)
at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:655)
at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:644)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:421)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:413)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:373)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:312)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1274)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1112)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1079)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:65)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)



I have overcome one problem after another and in this case I cannot find the answer. I have updated my maven dependencies.
Anyone knows what is the source of the error?


I am not an expert and also a fresher in Appium but the issue that appears here does not belong to session creation but rather capabilities. You can try below code to verify the calendar is opening in java.
DesiredCapabilities cap_1 = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap_1.setCapability("appium:deviceName","Galaxy A15 5G");
cap_1.setCapability("platformName","Android");
cap_1.setCapability("appium:platformVersion","14");
cap_1.setCapability("appium:udid","UDID_YOur_device");
cap_1.setCapability("appium:automationName", "UiAutomator2");
cap_1.setCapability("appium:appPackage","com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator");
cap_1.setCapability("appium:appActivity","com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator.Calculator");
URL url = new URL("appium_provided_url");
driver_mb1 = new AppiumDriver(url,cap_1);

